# Slow Macro, Solver and Formulas with UDFs

Tags: vba, performance, excel, user-defined-functions, solver

I am running VBA code that basically:

1. Sets certain cells equal certain values
2. These are fed into a model that produces a number
3. Solver is used to change an input and obtain the final number output

Number of loops is about 150, not too many.
This all takes place in Workbook 2. Calculations happen in Workbook 1.
In Workbook 1, there is quite a large number of cells with a User-Defined Function in them. About 4000 in total.

When running the VBA code the whole procedure takes over a minute to finish. If I delete the data in Worksheet 1 (as it is not need for this particular macro), then the VBA code only takes about 5 seconds. This is fine.

Is there a way to effectively turn off/ lock / ignore all these UDF cells from slowing down the macro? Just that range of data. I have tried ManualCalc Vs AutoCalc but does not seem to do that trick.

Thanks in advance

Anthony

Comment: You could exclude the problematic "worksheet 1" into another workbook as a workaround.

Comment: Yes that was the most likely option, thanks. The only issue is that the model would then have to have data updated for each workbook. Think of it like a "Model Sheet" in Worksheet 1, that brings in data from an outside program. Then Worksheets 2,3,4.. are analytics coming from that data. If I break the worksheet 1 out I'll need to bring the outside data into multiple workbooks as Solver will I assume need to reference something in the same workbook.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that when working with a solver VBA code should be limited only to the tool call. Turning off the AutoCalc will not do anything because the solver forces calculate for currently under consideration scenario. In my opinion you must necessarily use formulas because they are significantly faster calculate.

Comment: Solver achieves things that can't be done with formulas. Such as "what does the value of Cellx have to be such that *Complicated formula here* = y. The UDFs are in the sheets but not used by Solver.

Comment: Just make a simulation: Convert the cells that contain the UDF's into values and then run the solver.

Comment: And then turn them all back after the Solver finishes..? Not all of the cells have the same UDF